# Flink or Spark? when streaming is not important

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink

I recently have been comparing Spark and Flink for a **brand new** project. In this project, streaming feature is not so important. Batch analysis of ~90TB data is most important. Later I will apply ML and data mining in data analysis.

When searching around, I find lots of articles, presentations and videos claim Flink is the next generation analysis solution. Don't see much articles defending Spark. On the other hand, Spark is(or was?) very popular and widely deployed in very large production system.

**My question is**: For my use case, i.e. streaming is not important, shall I embrace Flink or start with Spark 2?

BTW, I've read through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082581/what-is-the-difference-between-apache-spark-and-apache-flink). It doesn't give me a good answer.

**Update, April 2018**: Eventually we choose Spark. Apparently there are more questions to address other than performance. Cloudera, Hortonworks and HDInsight give a good level of confidence/proof in security, stability, scale, roadmap etc. to enterprise architects and security reviewers.

Comment: That thread mentioning Spark 1.5 and earlier is woefully outdated. While I can't speak much to Flink, I can speak comfortably about Spark and it's an incredibly powerful tool that can be adapted extensively

Comment: Exactly, not much information about Spark 2 vs Flink. For a brand new project, I am a bit confused which one to choose.

Comment: At this point in Flink's development, I would still advise production systems leaning toward Spark unless extensive testing has been done on Flink to ensure it will meet expectations. I'm looking into doing benchmarks on the two to see for myself.

Comment: I did a quick test on my MacBook making sure to compare Spark to Flink fairly. I lauched spark-shell and ran a simple line count of a 17GB directory with text files which took 27 seconds. I then tried it in Flink. At first, the result was pathetic (160+ seconds), so I looked into CPU usage which was low. I then edited the flink-conf.yaml to use 8 task slots, restarted the server, did a `benv.setParallelism(8)` in the scala Flink shell, and ran the same line count. Flink took 81 seconds this time using 8 task slots. Better but poor scaling (8x more slots ~1/2 the time) :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your requirement, **Apache Spark is best**. Both **Spark** and **Flink** are advanced big data processing technologies. In terms of **features**, **stability**, **ecosystem**, **community**, **integrations** **with other systems** and **adaptability** **Spark** is much ahead of **Flink**.

The major difference between **Spark** and **Flink** is: **Spark** is a **batch** processing system and it has **streaming** abstraction whereas **Flink** is **stream** data processing system for processing **unbounded** datasets and it has **batch** processing abstraction to process **bounded** datasets in batch style.

Spark is best for **ETL**, **Machine Learning, Streaming, data warehousing** and **Graph processing** on large volumes of datasets. Flink is best for **stream processing** on large and **unbounded** datasets.

[Apache-Flink]
[Apache-Spark]